# Excel Vba, load picture from folder

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying a macro to load a picture from a folder with the name of the cell value.

So
Value:
Q2 = Where is the dog
then i want to load the picture 'Where is the dog.jpg'
in cells c2:E2

The value of cell Q2 changes when a other macro is runs.

I have some blackout here, because cann't get it working.

Here is the code:

```
       Set PicRange = Sheet1.Range("C2:E14")


       Filepath = "C:\Pictures\"
       Filename = Filepath & Sheet1.Range("Q2").Value & ".jpg"

        If Dir(Filename) = "" Then MsgBox "Nothing!"
        Exit Sub

        With PicRange
            Set Pic = Sheet1.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename, msoFalse, msoTrue, .Left, .Top, .Columns.Width, .Rows.Height)

        End With
```

The picture will not display

Comment: update your question with the code you currently have and tell us where it is not working

Answer (score 7):

The way your code is written, it will always `Exit Sub` before adding the picture.

Write your `If` block like this:

```
If Dir(Filename) = "" Then 
    MsgBox "Nothing!"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: @dave - if this solved your issue, please mark as answered (green check box)